# Where to put class declaration of classes meant as parameter hints?

Tags: php, class, oop

Say you have an MVC folder structure

- controllers/
- models/
- views/

In models you have:

```
class FooModel
{
    public function getName(FooData $data)
    {
        return $data->name;
    }

}
```

As you can see `getName` method needs it's parameter to be of `FooData` type.

Where do you usually put the class declaration of `FooData`? E.g.:

```
class FooData
{   
    public $name;
}
```

Is it usually just underneath the class declaration of `FooModel` or in an "interfaces" folder perhaps?

Comment: What is `FooData`? Is it some random object or what does it represents? And why echo in model? Why model does not outputs it's own name/does not handles it's own data?

Comment: @Justinas `showName` needs its parameter to be of type `FooData` because `FooData` has some specific requirements. E.g., it must have `$name` property, etc.

Comment: @Justinas I was just putting a quick sample. I have edited it now.

Comment: I think you most set fooData in models dependence of  MVC pattern: Look at this: https://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html * A model is an object representing data or even activity, e.g. a database table or even some plant-floor production-machine process....

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad You mean inside `models/` folder on it's own file e.g., `FooData.php`?

Comment: Yes, IMB...Since a model will be control data from tables or any other process related to model..

Comment: If you need to get a quality answer, you should add more concrete information to your question, because placing of FooData class depends on its role in a system.

Comment: Some time if we have a lot of things like this, we build an helperClass & ComponentClasses....also in php we can use traits..to help us some time...theres a lot of ways may be handling related classes and models ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependence of MVC definition we can answer by this:

> You can put your fooData in models

Since theirs no requirement to prevent other class with no direct relation to be inside Models in mvc.

Some Definition for MVC Model:

> A model is an object representing data or even activity, e.g. a database table or even some plant-floor production-machine process
>
> The model is the central component of the pattern. It is the application's dynamic data structure, independent of the user interface.[6] It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application.

Ref:
[MVC-1](https://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html)
[Wiki MVC-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Also in other technique you can build a new directory to put not related class Like helper folder / component folder.

Note: Sure these words not compatible with third party classes!